# How to order a collection of a habtm-association by created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three main Classes: Users, Vocabs and Tags. A User has many Tags. Tags has-and-belongs-to-many Vocabs (and the other way around). 
How can I order a collection of Tags when getting them through a Vocab-Object?

```
@vocab.tag
```

gets the tags from the joins table, which has no created_at column.
Is there a handy way to solve this problem?

I am pretty new to Rails so excuse me if this is obvious.

EDIT: I just tried

```
@tags = @vocab.tags.order('tags.created_at DESC')
```

but without success.

The computer says:

```
Started GET "/users/1/vocabs/61" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 15:41:15 +0100
Processing by VocabsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"61"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Vocab Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "vocabs".* FROM "vocabs"  WHERE "vocabs"."user_id" = ? AND "vocabs"."id"      
                    = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 61]]
Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "tags_vocabs" ON "tags"."id" = 
                  "tags_vocabs"."tag_id" WHERE "tags_vocabs"."vocab_id" = ?  [["vocab_id", 61]]
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
Rendered vocabs/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.7ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 602ms (Views: 587.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
def new_tag
  @user = current_user
  @vocab = @user.vocabs.find(params[:id])
  @tags = @vocab.tags.order('tags.created_at DESC')
  @tag = current_user.tags.build(name: params[:tag])

  if @tag.save
    @vocab.tags<<@tag
    flash.now[:success] ='Tag successfully created.'
    redirect_to user_vocab_path(@user, @vocab)
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "Tag could not be created!"
    render :action => "show"
  end
end
```

Comment: You say `tags` have no `created_at`. No? Try `vocabs.created_at` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't that sort the tags by the created_at value of the vocab they belong to? I want them sorted by the created_at value in the Tags-table.

Comment: I added the server-reply in my question.

Comment: Weird. No `ORDER`? Try executing the following in a Rails console, what SQL does it produce? `Vocab.first.tags.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: I was also wondering why it doesn't show any sign of the order statement there... Your command looks good though, it gives me the tags in right order.I will try to use it like that in the controller.

Comment: Weird. In the controller it doesn't work, again no sign of the order statement while it worked perfectly in the rails console.

Comment: Try `reorder` instead of `order`. No idea why it's needed though...

Comment: Didn't help. Thx though for trying to help...